# Misprints in a book as Poisson process

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Suppose that a book with $n$ pages contains on the average $λ$ misprints per page. What is the probability that there will be at least $m$ pages which contain more than $k$ misprints ?

I am getting two answers by two approaches, which one is wrong ?

---

Method $1$ :

If there are $m$ pages with at least $k$ misprints then there are a total of at least $mk$ misprints. Now the number of total misprints in the book is a Poisson with $\lambda n$ rate. Hence the probability becomes
$$\sum_{t=mk}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda n}(\lambda n)^{t}}{t!}$$

---

Method 2:

On a single page the probaility that there are at least $k$ misprints is $p = \sum_{i=k+1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^i}{i!}$. Therefore the proabibility of a page having less than or equal to $k$ misprints is $1-p$. Now there are total $n$ pages we can have at least $m$ pages with $k$ misprints, then total probability is 
$$\sum_{x = m}^{n} {n\choose x}p^x(1-p)^{n-x}$$

Comment: Method 1 computes the probability that there are at least $mk$ misprints in total. This can happen even if less than $m$ pages have at least $k$ misprints.

Comment: I didn't think about that. Thanks now I understand :)

Comment: Method 2 is right, but with a slight wording change to match the question: "... there are more than $k$ misprints is $p$...."